# Unable to fetch authorization code for OAuth2.0 with Pentaho PDI rest client

Tags: oauth-2.0, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am unable the fetch authorization code in the response message for an OAuth2.0 connection. Output message :

```
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: \u0026#39;scope\u0026#39
```

[image: Issue screenshot]

Basically I am facing issue with passing the body parameters in the Pentaho rest client and authenticating the scope url. I am using POST request and passing the body in JSON format.

BODY:

```
{"scope":${SCOPE},"client_id":${CLIENT_ID},"redirect_uri":${REDIRECT_URI},"response_type":${RESPONSE_TYPE},"grant_type":${GRANT_TYPE}}.
```

URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

**Tried:**
I have tried getting autorization code by using below call from chrome and it is working fine and returning the code.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/e7c47320-8eba-4356-aad3-18c1dd75004a/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope={scope}&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type={code}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/e7c47320-8eba-4356-aad3-18c1dd75004a/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=%7Bscope%7D&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&response_type=%7Bcode%7D).

I have also tried POST and GET method of rest client and it is failing with the same response.